# Object oriented lua classes leaking

Tags: lua

I've read quite a bit about object oriented lua (setting the metatable), and i have constructed a system, complete with inheritance.

My problem is now, that some of the variables seem to be leaking into each other. if i call a function called `window:click(x, y)` the function calls just fine. the job of this function is the notify all my components of a click. which it is doing

```
for number, component in pairs(self.components) do
    component.focus = false
    component:click(x, y, msg)
end
```

`self.components` contains all the components of the window

To act as a baseclass for all the components i have a class called component.lua, this file creates a table called components, and adds a `create()` method to it (that does all the usual OO lua stuff), this baseclass contains all the methods and variables i want in all my components, including `component:click(x, y)` and once again, it get's called.

```
for key, callback in pairs(self.clickCallback) do
    callback()
end
return
```

the `clickCallback` table contains functions that should be called when the component is notified. and is initialized inside component.lua

From here i inherit this class over to my other classes, simply by setting my metatable of my new component (textbox, button, label etc.). These components are what get's added to the `self.components` table in the window.

The problem is that each of these components should have their own clickCallback table. Which i am writing to via a setter in `component.lua`

```
function component:addClickHandler(handler)
    table.insert(self.clickCallback, handler)
end
```

but when i call `click(x,y)` on one component it calls all the clickHandlers, whether that be for another button or a label.

As you could see above, i am setting a parameter called `focus` this seems to experience the same problem, where setting it for one component (as you can see i am looping through each of them) sets it for all (so if i have 4 components the focus gets reset 4 times on each component)

Why is lua doing this, and what can be done to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's vastly more difficult to try to figure out what's going on from your little snippets that if you just posted a complete working example demonstrating the problem.

> self.components contains all the components of the window

This is probably your problem right here. Again, this is a guess, because you didn't show the `create` method, but if your constructor is not initializing a `clickCallback` member for each *instance*, then it's going to use the table in the class itself.

Here's an example illustrating the problem:

```
component = {}
component.__index = component

component.clickCallback = {}

function component.create()
  return setmetatable({}, component)
end

function component:addClickHandler(handler)
  table.insert(self.clickCallback, handler)
end

function component:click(x,y)
  for _,callback in pairs(self.clickCallback) do
      callback(x,y)
  end
end

a = component.create()
b = component.create()

a:addClickHandler(function(x,y) print("a", x, y) end)
b:addClickHandler(function(x,y) print("b", x, y) end)

a:click(10,20)
b:click(11,22)
```

Here's the output, which shows the symptom you described:

```
a       10      20
b       10      20
a       11      22
b       11      22
```

In other words, calling `a:click` calls the handler for `a` and `b`, because the `clickCallback` table is in the class itself, being shared by all instances of that class. The fix it make sure each instance has it's own handler table:

```
component = {}
component.__index = component

function component.create()
  return setmetatable({ clickCallback = {}}, component)
end

function component:addClickHandler(handler)
  table.insert(self.clickCallback, handler)
end

function component:click(x,y)
  for _,callback in pairs(self.clickCallback) do
      callback(x,y)
  end
end

a = component.create()
b = component.create()

a:addClickHandler(function(x,y) print("a", x, y) end)
b:addClickHandler(function(x,y) print("b", x, y) end)

a:click(10,20)
b:click(11,22)
```

Output:

```
a       10      20
b       11      22
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was unable to provide a working example, as the API i am hooking to is unreleased. but what you constructed from my snippets is pretty close to what i have, and the solution you provided worked. so thank you!